# android search array from csv

Tags: android, arrays, csv

I need some help. Im quite new to android and java.

Right now i have a csv code reader. The code will read the csv and then puts it into a Spinner. the csv file i have is example like this

`1,"Easy"
2,"Medium"
3,"Hard"
4, "Very Hard`

My Code

```
try{

    InputStreamReader csvStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(MainActivity.this.getAssets().open("Category.csv"));

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(csvStreamReader);
    Log.d("test", "reading csv");

    String [] nextLine;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

            list.add(nextLine[0] + "," + nextLine[1]);}                spinner1 =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code works well. It does appear in the spinner. 
Now i want to go a little further, i want to create a for loop the check the array for a particular text example "Medium". When the word is found, it will be stored into another array. I really cant figure out the code. Try searching for ideas in this forum but fail. Can some one give me some pointers, preferred a sample code.

Comment: check whats there in the list. BTW I dont see the ending brace for while. Would like to check that ass well.

Comment: `i want to create a for loop the check the array for a particular text example "Medium". When the word is found, it will be stored into another array. I really cant figure out the code. `. What is the problem exactly? Coding a loop? Search a string? Adding to an arraylist?

Comment: Hi. When i pasted the code i miss the brace. My question is a little confusing. How do you search an array for certain word?